# PySpark createDataFrame with schema indices error

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create a PySpark dataframe from a numpy array of shape (125,3) with a 3 column schema. It works fine for me with 2 columns, but as soon as I go above 2 columns I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (125, 3), indices imply (125, 2)
```

From the docs, and lots of examples online, this can be done using StructType and StructField, so I am confused why I am having this issue:
[PySpark docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjrnn.png)

**Example Code:**

```
prob_row_schema = StructType([
    StructField('field1', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('field2', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('field3', IntegerType(), True),
])

df1= pd.DataFrame(range(1,5+1), columns=['field1'])
df2= pd.DataFrame(range(1,5+1), columns=['field2'])
df3= pd.DataFrame(range(1,5+1), columns=['field3'])
df= df1.join(df2, how='cross').join(df3, how='cross')
x = df.values

df_prob = spark.createDataFrame(data=x, schema = prob_row_schema)
```

FYI: cross joining gives all unique combinations -> 125 rows

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this code works for me perfectly fine. what is your pyspark version?

Comment: Ok, good to know. I am using PySpark 3.3.0, what version were you using?

Comment: For anyone encountering this issue, it was eventually fixed by upgrading to the latest Databricks Runtime Version (13.3 LTS from 11.3 LTS)